# How can I refresh the list after changes?

Tags: android, refresh

I use my ArrayAdapter expanded getView method.
I change CheckBox but the ListView does not refresh

my source

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Planet to display
        UrlItem urlItem = (UrlItem) this.getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.database_table_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);



            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                            DatabaseTable.setPosition(getPosition);


                            for (int i = 0; i < UrlItems.size(); i ++ ) {

                                UrlItems.get(i).setUse(false);

                            }

                            UrlItems.get(getPosition).setUse(isChecked);


                        }
                    });
```

**How can I refresh the list after changes ??**

for your information in the manifest set

```
<activity
            android:name=".DatabaseTable"
            android:label="database_table" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

See the link for the upgrade using the button "selectAll" I have exact same idea but without the button selectAll

http://pastebin.com/PgNeDnXq

Comment: in my Activity `uAdapter = new UrlArrayAdapter(DatabaseTable.this, urlListView,
    urlLists);

  urlListView.setAdapter(uAdapter);`

Comment: As a tip, rather than create a new OnCheckedChangeListener for every row, you should save this listener in a class variable and pass it to each Checkbox. By reusing this listener you'll save resourcse and have a faster app.

Comment: how to do it. Can a small example?

Comment: Outside of getView(), but still in you Adapter class declare this variable: `OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() { ... }`. In getView() use `viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // to notify the adapter that your data has been updated
```

**Note:** If you get any errors with the above line, you could try the following code (where mListView is the name of my ListView object)

```
((BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Another way would be to invalidate the List so that it is redrawn form the updated data set once again.

```
mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
mListView.invalidate();
```

Comment: get any errors =( But I see you have understood the need to somehow twist

Comment: mListView.getAdapter() - nullExepyion because urlListView.setAdapter(uAdapter); - comes after link (http://pastebin.com/PgNeDnXq) they use the buttons as I have without her

Comment: See the link for the upgrade using the button "selectAll" I have exact same idea but without the button selectAll

Comment: Why dont you just make a reference to the ListView in your XML and invalidate() it ?

Comment: not obtained, the error, If I do not understand something please give an example

Comment: all you need to write is ListView mListView; (as a data member in your class) and then inside onCreate(), add this line mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView); And then, call mListView.invalidate() when you would want to refresh the list contents.

Comment: invalidate might work but it's not the proper way of doing it. The proper way is through the notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Budius : I totally agree with you! But in case it doesn't work, I was just suggesting a workaround.

Comment: @swayam I understand but, my point is: If it doesn't work, it's not being properly implemented. So it's better to fix to the correct implementation than creating workarounds for something that must work.

Comment: @Budius : I cant really disagree on that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

notify that the data set have changed ; )

Comment: Since you haven't told us what it is called he made up a generic name, you should replace it with the identifier of your adapter. That solution should work if implemented correctly.

Comment: mAdapter is a generic name for an Adapter. For your code you should change to whatever you're calling your instance of ArrayAdapter

Comment: You do not understand the method getView class UrlArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter

Comment: and what is the name of the instance of the UrlArrayAdapter class? **edit: ** Just saw your comment, so the code is uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I know about you, but I think it does not work, give an example

Comment: that is the whole code. Inside your OnCheckedChangeListener, after the database operations you call notifyDataSetChanged(); to tell the adapter the data have changed and it will update the views for the ViewGroup with the new data.

Comment: Well let me try ... I will answer later