# Android Refresh ListActivity from BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListActivity and a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter.

On each row of the ListView, there is a button and a few more views.  onClickListener is declared in the adapter.

How can I **refresh list view** after button is clicked ?

Here is the code

**List Activity:**

```
 .........
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


here im reading content from a file and then creating adapter with that content

     adapter = new UvArrayAdapter(this, strarray3, strarray2, intarray);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
 ..........
```

**Adapter:**

```
.......

 public class UvArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private Context mContext;
 private LayoutInflater linflater;
 private TextView txt_1, txt_2, txt_3;
 private ProgressBar pr1;
private String[] str1;
private String[] str2;
private String[] str3;
private Integer[] int1;

private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{       
    private int mPosition;
    OnItemClickListener(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.v("TAG", "onItemClick at position" + mPosition);          
    }       
}



public UvArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] s1, String[] s2, Integer[] i1) {
mContext = context;
str1 = s1;
 str2 = s2;
int1 = i1;
linflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return str1.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
return str1[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
return arg0;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.uv_rowlayout, null);

}
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
txt_1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
pr1 = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
pr1.setProgress(int1[position]);
txt_1.setText(str1[position]);

txt_2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
txt_2.setText(str2[position]+"mV");
Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.v("onClickListener", "button - clicked at position "             position);

        do some changes in mentioned file and after that i need to update the list view with new data
             }});




return convertView;

}



}
```

Comment: repeat question from 22min ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972259/how-can-i-refresh-the-list-after-changes

Answer (score 4):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // to notify the adapter that your data has been updated
```

**Note:** If you get any errors with the above line, you could try the following code (where mListView is the name of my ListView object)

```
((BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Another way would be to invalidate the List so that it is redrawn form the updated data set once again.

```
mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
mListView.invalidate();
```

Comment: please give me an example, i dont know how to implement that in my code

Comment: mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
mListView.invalidate();
This is all you need to use instead of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Make sure your R.id.nameOfYourListViewInXML is same in the findViewById function.

Comment: mListView is the name of your ListView in the java code. I guess since you are using ListActivity, you havent used it explicitly. Anyway, all you need to write is ListView mListView; (as a data member in your class) and then inside onCreate(), add this line mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);

Comment: Whatever is the name of the ListView in the XML file.

Comment: there is no list view. i use custom made layout for adapter. It has progres bar button and 2 textViews

Comment: In that case, I do not know how it works. If you would want to invalidate it, my suggestion would be to add a ListView in your xml and reference it in your java code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
adapter = new UvArrayAdapter(this, strarray3, strarray2, intarray);
setListAdapter(adapter);
UvArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

// To make the adapter aware of the changes
```

Comment: again same error      Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method notifyDataSetChanged() from the type BaseAdapter